# Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 set null parameter not working

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have two parameters in my SQL query, and I want NAME_ can be set to null, this is the way I write it:

```
SELECT * FROM DATASET WHERE DATE_=(@DATE_) AND NAME_=(@NAME_) OR NAME_ IS NULL
```

When NAME_ is null, I want to select all items where DATE_=(@DATE_), which means:

```
 SELECT * FROM DATASET WHERE DATE=(@DATE_)
```

When NAME_ is not null, it acts like:

```
 SELECT * FROM DATASET WHERE DATE_=(@DATE_) AND NAME_=(@NAME_)
```

And the possible value of @NAME_ is from a query

```
SELECT NAME_ FROM DATASET WHERE DATE_=(@DATE_)
```

I ticked "Allow null value" in parameter properties but every time I run the Report it still alert me to choose a NAME_ value.

I don't know anything else I could do to make null value possible. Any advice will be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this:

```
WHERE ColumnName = ISNULL(@ParamValue, ColumnName)
```

This lets the dataset know that if the variable is set then use it, else have an operator to have the value equal to itself.

Applied to your example:

```
SELECT * FROM DATASET WHERE DATE_=(@DATE_) AND NAME_= ISNULL((@NAME_), NAME_)
```

Comment: Thank you! And another thing is I already ticked "Allow null value", but the system alert me choose a value still. Is it related to the other parameter since @DATE_ is a parameter of @NAME_?

Comment: Try unchecking the "Allow multiple values" checkbox for that parameters.

Comment: I didn't tick it. The situation is before I pick value for DATE there is a null tick box but after I choosing a DATE ,the box disappear.  DATE is a parameter of NAME.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,use WHERE ColumnName = ISNULL(@ParamValue, ColumnName) as Oceans said. Then in the query of parameter, "SELECT NULL FROM DATASET" should be union. Finally tick "Allow null value"; In my case, it should be following steps:

1. `SELECT * FROM DATASET WHERE DATE_=(@DATE_) AND NAME_= ISNULL((@NAME_), NAME_)`
2. In NAME_ select query: `SELECT NAME_ FROM DATASET WHERE DATE_=(@DATE_) UNION SELECT NULL FROM DATASET`
3. Tick "Allow null value" in parameter setting of NAME_